# How to add caption and fix the position of table in latex?

Tags: latex

I'm tying to read a cvx file and make table in latex.
I'm using `\csvautotabular{Figures/Mytable.csv}`
$. What is missing is that:
I don't know how to fix the position of the table in may chapter. Second, how to add caption for it.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `\csvautotabular` in a `table` environment and adding a `\caption` should work.

Similar to what is done in [this stackexchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431080).

Answer (score 0):

Like char's answer, you can do:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \csvautotabular{tables/my-table.csv}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```